# March Madness Simulator

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

It's a march madness simulator for the final 4!!!

Please be as critical as you can :)

```
# March Madness Program

import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import re
import time

def getTeams():
    """ Get team data """
    website = 'http://www.ncaa.com/rankings/basketball-men/d1'
    siteData = urllib3.PoolManager().request('GET',
                                             website).data
    try:
        teams = []
        soup = BeautifulSoup(siteData, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find_all('table','ncaa-rankings-table')[0]
        for i, row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
            if 1 <= i <= 4:
                team = {}
                for i, child in enumerate(row.children):
                    text = child.string
                    if i == 0:
                        team['seed'] = int(text)
                    elif i == 1:
                        team['name'] = text.split()[0]
                    elif i == 2:
                        team['record'] = [int(i) for i in text.split('-')]
                team['beaten'] = []
                team['eliminated'] = False
                teams.append(team)
        if len(teams) == 4:
            return teams
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except Exception:
        return [
            {
                'name': 'Florida Gators',
                'seed': 4,
                'record': [24, 8],
                'beaten': [],
                'eliminated': False
            }, {
                'name': 'UCLA Bruins',
                'seed': 3,
                'record': [29, 4],
                'beaten': [],
                'eliminated': False
            }, {
                'name': 'Duke Blue Devils',
                'seed': 2,
                'record': [27, 8],
                'beaten': [],
                'eliminated': False
            }, {
                'name': 'North Carolina Tar Heels',
                'seed': 1,
                'record': [27, 7],
                'beaten': [],
                'eliminated': False
            }
        ]

def sortSeed(*teams, k=0):
    return sorted(teams, key=lambda x: x['seed'])[k]

class Matchup(object):
    strings = [
        [
            'Welcome to the matchup between team1.seed team1.name and team2.seed team2.name.\n' + \
            'favorite.name is the favorite in today\'s matchup.\n' + \
            'Game in Progress',
            'winner.name defeated loser.name!'
        ], [
            'It\'s a beautiful day out here!\n' + \
            'All the spectators are prepared to see favorite.name\n' + \
            'demolish bad.name!\n' + \
            'Game in Progress',
            'Would you look at that? winner.name won the match!'
        ]
    ]
    pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)\.(\w+)')

    @classmethod
    def parseString(cls, strg, kwargs):
        matches = cls.pattern.findall(strg)
        for match in matches:
            strg = strg.replace(match[0]+'.'+match[1], str(kwargs[match[0]][match[1]]))
        return strg

    @staticmethod
    def displayFakeLoad(slpTime=3, loops=3):
        slpTime = slpTime/loops
        for i in range(loops):
            print('.', end='')
            time.sleep(slpTime)
        print()

    @classmethod
    def displayMatchup(cls, kwargs, pFunc=print):
        t1, t2 = kwargs['team1'], kwargs['team2']
        kwargs['loser'] = t2 if kwargs['winner'] == t1 else t1
        kwargs['favorite'] = sortSeed(t1, t2)
        kwargs['bad'] = sortSeed(t1, t2, k=1)
        gameString = random.choice(cls.strings)
        printGameString = lambda x, e=False: pFunc(cls.parseString(gameString[x],
                                                                   kwargs),
                                                   end='' if e else '\n')
        printGameString(0, True)
        cls.displayFakeLoad()
        printGameString(1)

        return kwargs

def playMatch(*args, slpTime=2):
    kwargs = {
        'team1': args[0],
        'team2': args[1]
    }
    roll = random.randrange(3)
    if roll < 2:
        winner = args[roll]
    else:
        winner = sortSeed(*args)
    kwargs['winner'] = winner
    kwargs = Matchup.displayMatchup(kwargs)
    kwargs['loser']['eliminated'] = True
    kwargs['loser']['record'][1] += 1
    kwargs['winner']['record'][0] += 1
    kwargs['winner']['beaten'].append(kwargs['loser'])
    time.sleep(slpTime)
    return kwargs['winner']

def printTeamInfo(teams):
    for team in teams:
        print(team['name'])
        print('\tSeed:   {}'.format(team['seed']))
        print('\tRecord: {}, {}'.format(*team['record']))
        print()

def main():
    teams = getTeams()
    print('There are {} teams in the tourney'.format(len(teams)))
    print('Here is team information:')
    print()
    printTeamInfo(teams)
    winners = []
    for n1, n2 in ((0,3),(1,2)):
        winners.append(playMatch(teams[n1],teams[n2]))
        print()
    winner = playMatch(*winners)
    print()
    print('{} has won it all!'.format(winner['name']))
    print()
    print('Team information, after the games:')
    print()
    printTeamInfo(teams)

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

**General things to improve:**

- fix the camelCase naming - follow [`PEP8` function and class method naming guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
- organize imports per PEP8 ([reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports))
- put your `main()` function call to under the [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to avoid it being executed on import:

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```
- avoid hardcoded values like the list of teams you return on any exception in `getTeams()` function. define this list as a constant:

  ```
  DEFAULT_TEAM_LIST = [...]
  ```

  You may go further and keep the default team list in a JSON file which you would load if you cannot scrape the team data..
- [avoid catching bare exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements)
- to ease debugging, specify a *meaningful error message* when raising built-in exceptions. Instead of `raise ValueError`, do something like `raise ValueError("The scraped number of teams is not 4.")`
- use [multi-line strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string) (for the `strings` variable definition and to replace multiple consecutive prints)
- some functions and methods are not easily understandable - add helpful docstrings and comments
- it feels like the `Matchup` class (which has only class methods defined) should be just a separate module which you would import from your main script

**Scraping the teams improvements:**

You can seriously improve the `getTeams()` function by replacing the `enumerate()` and index check with a slice, locating the table rows with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and improving the way you select the row cell texts:

```
teams = []
for row in soup.select('table.ncaa-rankings-table tr')[1:5]:  # get 4 top rows skipping the header
    seed, name, record = row('td')[:3]  # get first 3 columns
    teams.append({
        'seed': int(seed.get_text()),
        'name': name.get_text(),
        'record': [int(item) for item in record.get_text().split("-")],
        'beaten': [],
        'eliminated': False
    })
```